# How to adjust the height of YouTubePlayer in Angular2

Tags: css, html, angular, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I am embedding a youtube video into my website that is developed using `Angular2`. I have created a small component called `video-player` for this and I am initiating the player in `.ts` as follows:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.player = YouTubePlayer('video-player', {
      videoId: this.videoPlayerData.videoURL,
      width: "100%",
      height: "400"
    });
}
```

As you can see I am controlling the height of the player in `.ts` itself. Can I control this height in `.css`?

*Why do I want to control height in `.css`?*

Because then I can adjust the size according to viewport height. I want it to be of `80vh`.

*What have I tried so far?*

1. Tried changing the player height to `80vh` in `.ts`, but did not work. Probably typescript only takes values.
2. Tried creating following `.css` class with desired height, but did not work.

css:

```
.player {
    height: 80vh;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="aspect-ratio player" id='video-player'></div>
```

Comment: What happens when you make `height: "80%"`?

Comment: Any percentage "0-800%" seems to have no effect at all. The height of the player becomes very small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

your div has 2 class names and one ID... so to be specific in CSS with multiple classes and/or ids you need to make a specific call.

```
<div class="aspect-ratio" id="video-player"></div>
```

your CSS call should look something like this

```
video-player.aspect-ratio {
  height: 80vh;
}
```

let me know what happens with this.

Comment: No effect at all. Changed height from 0-120vh. It was stubborn. :(

Comment: sorry the css part looks like it was a miss type:

`#video-player.aspect-ratio`

also, have you considered setting it into another div setting the size of that div to what you want and leaving the video player div the height and width of 100% in the .ts file?

Comment: Adding another div worked. Quite embarrassing that I could not think of that myself! :P

Comment: @SonuMishra glad to help you out!!